# What causes the artifacts in dynamically created gif?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif, image-manipulation, artifact

I'm dynamically creating a GIF using PIL and I get this artifact at the tip of Charizard's wings
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Pj9.jpg
Below is the code I'm using to create the gif, I thought by pasting a new background to the gif it wouldn't cause this issue but it looks like that isn't doing anything.

```
        images = []
        length = min(pokemonImage1.n_frames, pokemonImage2.n_frames)
        for frameIndex in range(0, length):
            pokemonImage1.seek(frameIndex)
            pokemonImage2.seek(frameIndex)
            pkmn1 = pokemonImage1.convert("RGBA")
            pkmn2 = pokemonImage2.convert("RGBA")
            imageInMemory = BytesIO()
            new_img = Image.new('RGBA', (800,400), (0, 0, 0, 0))
            new_img.paste(background, (0,0))
            new_img.paste(pkmn1, (600, 100), mask=pkmn1)
            new_img.paste(pkmn2, (100, 300), mask=pkmn2)
            new_img.save(imageInMemory, 'png')
            imageInMemory.name = "gifInMemory_" + str(frameIndex) + ".png"
            images.append(Image.open(imageInMemory))
            
        gifInMemory = BytesIO()
        images[0].save(gifInMemory, "gif", save_all=True, append_images=images[1:], loop=0, optimize=True, duration=20)
        gifInMemory.name = "battle.gif"
        gifInMemory.seek(0)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `disposal` parameter of `Image.save()`? This parameter affects how the previous frame is disposed in relation to the background. Try adding `disposal=2` and see if that helps. ([documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#gif))

Comment: I just tried it but unfortunately that doesn't seem to do anything.

I think the issue is happening in the for loop since the images in the loop have the artifact

Comment: Interestingly enough when I add a bounding box to the gif, it doesn't have the artifacts anymore. If I set the bounding box's alpha to 0 the artifacts re-appear. 
https://imgur.com/a/aQDUTOe